# Use hits sent by GA4 in Google Tag Manager to get events parameters

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

does anyone know if it is possible to use the parameters of an event sent with the hits of the event itself from Google Analytics with the Google Tag Manager?

[page_view hit details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpa58.png)

As you can see from this screenshot, the page_view event includes many parameters, such as Page Title, Session Engagement, and many others that are not natively tracked by GTM.

For example, if I wanted to get the value of the "seg" parameter via GTM, how can I do it?

Thank you

I tried using a custom JavaScript but I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  GTM doesn't give you the ability to monitor network requests.  Even though you may be sending the request via GTM to GA, it's not going to show you the request details or the response.